# React.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting error after taking a React `render` from something like this

```
            return (
                React.createElement('form', {
                        onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
                        className: 'ContactForm',
                        noValidate: true
                    },
                    React.createElement('input', {
                        type: 'text',
                        className: errors.name && 'ContactForm-error',
                        placeholder: 'Name',
                        onInput: this.onNameInput,
                        value: this.props.value.name,
                    }),
                    React.createElement('button', {
                        type: 'submit'
                    }, "Add Contact")
                )
            );
```

to something like this

```
            function create_input_element(type, fieldname){
                var capital_fieldname = capitalize(fieldname);
                return React.createElement('input', {
                    type: type,
                    className: errors[fieldname] && 'ContactForm-error',
                    placeholder: capitalize(capital_fieldname),
                    onInput: this['on' + capital_fieldname + 'Input'],
                    value: this.props.value[fieldname],
                    autoFocus: true,
                })
            }
        
           create_input_element('text', 'name')
```

The issue is at `this.props.value[fieldname]`, and even `this.props.value.name` will break with the same error.

The exact code is

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .ContactView-title {
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 0 24px;
        }

        .ContactView-list {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
        }

        .ContactItem {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 8px 24px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
        }

        .ContactItem-email {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .ContactItem-name {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-top: 4px;
            font-style: italic;
            color: #888;
        }

        .ContactItem-description {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

        .ContactForm {
            padding: 8px 24px;
        }

        .ContactForm>input {
            display: block;
            width: 240px;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .ContactForm>input.ContactForm-error {
            border-color: #b30e2f;
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="description" content="Ridiculously Simple Forms with Raw React - Exercise Two">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zloirock/core-js/master/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="react-app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script>
        /*
         * Components
         */

         function capitalize(str){
             return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)
         }


        var ContactForm = React.createClass({
            propTypes: {
                value: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
                onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                onSubmit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            },

            onEmailInput: function(e) {
                this.props.onChange(Object.assign({}, this.props.value, {
                    email: e.target.value
                }));
            },

            onNameInput: function(e) {
                this.props.onChange(Object.assign({}, this.props.value, {
                    name: e.target.value
                }));
            },

            onSubmit: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.props.onSubmit();
            },

            render: function() {
                var errors = this.props.value.errors || {};

                function create_input_element(type, fieldname){
                    var capital_fieldname = capitalize(fieldname);
                    return React.createElement('input', {
                        type: type,
                        className: errors[fieldname] && 'ContactForm-error',
                        placeholder: capitalize(capital_fieldname),
                        onInput: this['on' + capital_fieldname + 'Input'],
                        value: this.props.value[fieldname],
                        autoFocus: true,
                    })
                }

                return (
                    React.createElement('form', {
                            onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
                            className: 'ContactForm',
                            noValidate: true
                        },
                        create_input_element('email', 'email'),
                        create_input_element('text', 'name'),
                        React.createElement('button', {
                            type: 'submit'
                        }, "Add Contact")
                    )
                );
            },
        });


        var ContactItem = React.createClass({
            propTypes: {
                name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                email: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            },

            render: function() {
                return (
                    React.createElement('li', {
                            className: 'ContactItem'
                        },
                        React.createElement('h2', {
                            className: 'ContactItem-email'
                        }, this.props.email),
                        React.createElement('span', {
                            className: 'ContactItem-name'
                        }, this.props.name)
                    )
                );
            },
        });


        var ContactView = React.createClass({
            propTypes: {
                contacts: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
                newContact: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
                onNewContactChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                onNewContactSubmit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            },

            render: function() {
                var contactItemElements = this.props.contacts
                    .map(function(contact) {
                        return React.createElement(ContactItem, contact);
                    });

                return (
                    React.createElement('div', {
                            className: 'ContactView'
                        },
                        React.createElement('h1', {
                            className: 'ContactView-title'
                        }, "Contacts"),
                        React.createElement('ul', {
                            className: 'ContactView-list'
                        }, contactItemElements),
                        React.createElement(ContactForm, {
                            value: this.props.newContact,
                            onChange: this.props.onNewContactChange,
                            onSubmit: this.props.onNewContactSubmit,
                        })
                    )
                );
            },
        });



        /*
         * Constants
         */


        var CONTACT_TEMPLATE = {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            description: "",
            errors: null
        };




        /*
         * Model
         */


        // The app's complete current state
        var state = {};

        // Make the given changes to the state and perform any required housekeeping
        function setState(changes) {
            Object.assign(state, changes);

            ReactDOM.render(
                React.createElement(ContactView, Object.assign({}, state, {
                    onNewContactChange: updateNewContact,
                    onNewContactSubmit: submitNewContact,
                })),
                document.getElementById('react-app')
            );
        }

        // Set initial data
        setState({
            contacts: [{
                key: 1,
                name: "James K Nelson - Front End Unicorn",
                email: "james@jamesknelson.com"
            }, {
                key: 2,
                name: "Jim",
                email: "jim@example.com"
            }, ],
            newContact: Object.assign({}, CONTACT_TEMPLATE),
        });



        /*
         * Actions
         */


        function updateNewContact(contact) {
            setState({
                newContact: contact
            });
        }


        function submitNewContact() {
            var contact = Object.assign({}, state.newContact, {
                key: state.contacts.length + 1,
                errors: {}
            });

            if (!/.+@.+\..+/.test(contact.email)) {
                contact.errors.email = ["Please enter your new contact's email"];
            }
            if (!contact.name) {
                contact.errors.name = ["Please enter your new contact's name"];
            }

            setState(
                Object.keys(contact.errors).length === 0 ?
                {
                    newContact: Object.assign({}, CONTACT_TEMPLATE),
                    contacts: state.contacts.slice(0).concat(contact),
                } :
                {
                    newContact: contact
                }
            );
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Why can't I generate `React.createElement()` things in a function?

Comment: Each function has its own `this` value (except arrow function). `this` inside `create_input_element` doesn't refer to your component instance. Have a look at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope problem. You can [learn here how the variable `this` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)  .

To solve your problem, you can use `call` to explicit pass `this` variable of the scope where the function is being invoked.

The code would look like like this: `create_input_element.call(this, 'email', 'email')`